# Can someone explain what this code does line by line? I am trying to convert VB code to python and have no knowledge of VB

Tags: python, vb6, vb6-migration

Can someone explain what this code does line by line?  I am trying to convert VB code to python and have no knowledge of VB. Couldn't figure out correctly from google.

```
FD = Split(STR, ",")

ReDim DMA((UBound(FD) + 1) / 2 - 1)

For n = 0 To UBound(FD)
    DMA(x).Stufe = FD(n)
    n = n + 1
    DMA(x).DirName = FD(n)
    x = x + 1
Next n
```

Comment: The only non-trivial thing here is ReDim - this sets array length. Other statements and operators are pretty generic or self-describing.

Answer (score 2):

I've added the Type defintion and array declaration provided below to the code sample.

```
' Type is VB's equivalent of a struct.
Type DM
  Stufe As Integer
  DirName As String
End Type

' Declare an array of the above Type (struc).
' At this point the array is still uninitialized, as no lower and/or upper array bounds is set, e.g.
' Dim DMA(2) As DM = lower bound is 0, upper is 2 or    
' Dim DMA(-5 To 10) As DM = lower bound is -5, upper is 10
Dim DMA() As DM

' Splits the string STR into an array of type Variant, using "," as the split delimiter in STR, 
' e.g. the string STR "1, C:\MyFolder" will result in FD(0) = 1, FD(1) = "C:\MyFolder"
' The array's lower bound is 0
FD = Split(STR, ",")

' To tell for sure, look for a previous Dim or ReDim of DMA. Arrays in VB can be Dim'd with any lower and upper boundary
' DMA is a Type (struct, see above declaration) with members .Stufe and .DirName.
' (Re)Dimensions the one-dimensional array DMA to
' Lower bound = (0, if not Dim'd or ReDim'd otherwise previously), 
' Upper bound = (upper bound of array FD + 1) / 2 - 1))
ReDim DMA((UBound(FD) + 1) / 2 - 1)


' Hint: "Stufe" is German for either "level" or "(e.g. door) step". I'd say "level" in the this case
' The loop itself should be self-explanatory
For n = 0 To UBound(FD)
    DMA(x).Stufe = FD(n)
    n = n + 1
    DMA(x).DirName = FD(n)
    x = x + 1
Next n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I would like to clarify few things.                                     1) DMA((UBound(FD) + 1) / 2 - 1) converts to  DMA = [(len(FD) + 1) / 2 - 1] in python...Please correct me if i am wrong.                                                                                                      
 2)I did not understand what is value of DMA(x).Stufe equals to and what does x represent . Type DM
    Stufe As Integer
    DirName As String
End Type
Dim DMA_Exists As Boolean
Dim DMA() As DM...This is the only refernce of DMA where it is declared

Comment: re 1) I don't really "speak" Python, but this sounds about right. re 2) VB doesn't distinguish between the comparison operator "=" _(e.g. "==" in C#)_ and the assignment operator "=" _(e.g. "=" in C#)_. In this case the value of the array element DMA(x) is assigned to the member .Stufe of the array element DMA(x), _(notation would be DMA[x] in Python, I think)_. Same for .DirName. I'm not a fan of how the For loop counter i is incremented manually inside the loop, but it seems to work.

Comment: Many languages would not allow incrementing the loop counter inside the loop. Does Python? Or it might ignore it, because it localizes the counter, or raise an error for the same reason. VB uses the `Step` keyword for this. I have no idea if Python supports the same construct.

Answer (score 1):

In VB(6)

```
Type DM
    Stufe As Integer
    DirName As String
End Type
```

DM is a user defined data type containing an integer 'Stufe' and a string 'DirName'.
DMA() is an array of DM types.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer below, it's not clear if DM ist a Type or a Class. An array of each would both result in the same assignment notation. foo(x).bar = value.

Comment: In the contect of the posted code (and assuming VB6 - no idea about vb.Net) I think it's got to be a type. I'd want to see the string before it's split at the start of the code, but from the subsequent code it's got to look something like: "1,Dirname1,2,Dirname2" and so on. It really needs type checking or conversion from a string to integer before .Stufe is allocated though.